# Generic LinkedLists in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am quite new to C and having a lot of trouble with generic linked lists in c.

Im trying to convert my linked list into a generic one but I don't really understand how to.

This is my original one:

```
typedef struct LLNode {
    int rowPos;
    int colPos
    char Charecter
    struct LLNode *next;
} LLNode;

typedef struct LinkedList {
    LLNode *head;
    LLNode *tail;
    int ROW;
    int COL;
    int appleCount;
    int winCon;
    int snakeSize;                                   
} LinkedList;
```

I understand that the data has to be a `void` but can you have more than one `void *data;` in a node.

So far I have this:

```
typedef struct LLNode {
    void *data;
    struct LLNode *next;
} LLNode;

typedef struct LinkedList {
    LLNode *head;
    LLNode *tail;
    int ROW;
    int COL;
    int appleCount;
    int winCon;
    int snakeSize;                                   
} LinkedList;
```

But I don't know how I go about accessing and changing 3 lots of data in one `void *data`.

Comment: I would probably go with macros as Ayxan suggests. Otherwise, you can always cast `data` to being a pointer to the type you've stored.

Comment: The easiest way is just to have `data` point to a struct. Then you can keep all your linked list logic separated from other logic. But it is not very pretty. Alternatively you could look at the implementation of linked lists in the Linux kernel. That uses some `offsetof` and can feel a bit like magic. It is a more elegant way than using macros but also a bit harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use macros:

```
#define LNODE(Type) LNode_ ## Type
#define LLIST(Type) LList_ ## Type

#define DECL_LINKED_LIST(Type) \
    typedef struct LNODE(Type) { Type value; struct LNODE(Type)* next; } LNODE(Type); \
    typedef struct LLIST(Type) { LNODE(Type)* head; LNODE(Type)* tail; } LLIST(Type);

typedef struct {
    char const* f_name;
    char const* l_name;
} Person;

DECL_LINKED_LIST(Person);

int main() {
    LLIST(Person) list;
    LNODE(Person) node1;

    list.head = list.tail = &node1;
    node1.next = 0;
    node1.value.f_name = "John";
    node1.value.l_name = "Smith";
}
```

It's somewhat ugly, but it works. Alternatively, if you can use a C++ compiler instead, you can use templates.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have typed generic aggregates such as C++ templates, but you can implement simpler aggregates pointing to data items via `void *` pointers. You can also use macros to mix the data and the aggregation internals, but it requires more advanced C skills.

Here is an example using `void *` for data:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* generic list handling */
typedef struct LLNode {
    struct LLNode *next;
    void *data;
} LLNode;

typedef struct LinkedList {
    LLNode *head;
    LLNode *tail;
} LinkedList[1];

void LinkedList_init(LinkedList list) {
    if (list) {
        list->head = list->tail = NULL;
    }
}

void *LinkedList_append(LinkedList list, void *data) {
    if (list) {
        LLNode *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
        if (node != NULL) {
            node->data = data;
            node->next = NULL;
            if (list->head == NULL) {
                list->head = list->tail = node;
            } else {
                list->tail = list->tail->next = node;
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *LinkedList_delete(LinkedList list, void *data) {
    if (list) {
        for (LLNode **np = &list->head, *last = NULL; *np;) {
            LLNode *node = *np;
            if (node->data == data) {
                if ((*np = node->next) == NULL)
                    list->tail = last;
                free(node);
                return data;
            } else {
                last = node;
                np = &node->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void LinkedList_free(LinkedList list, int free_data) {
    if (list) {
        for (LLNode *node = list->head, *next; node; node = next) {
            next = node->next;
            if (free_data)
                free(node->data);
            free(node);
        }
        list->head = list->tail = NULL;
    }
}

#define LinkedList_foreach(var, list) \
        for (LLNode *np__ = (list)->head, *next__; np__ != NULL; np__ = next__) \
            for (var = (next__ = np__->next, np__)->data; np__; np__ = NULL)

/* use a generic list for my data */
typedef struct MyData {
    int rowPos;
    int colPos;
    char Character;
} MyData;

typedef struct MyList {
    int ROW;
    int COL;
    int appleCount;
    int winCon;
    int snakeSize;
    LinkedList list;  // linked list of MyData items
} MyList;

MyList *MyList_alloc(void) {
    MyList *lp = calloc(sizeof(*lp), 1);
    LinkedList_init(lp->list);
    return lp;
}

void MyList_free(MyList *lp) {
    LinkedList_free(lp->list, 1);
    free(lp);
}

MyData *MyList_add(MyList *lp, int row, int col, char c) {
    MyData *dp = malloc(sizeof(*dp));
    dp->rowPos = row;
    dp->colPos = col;
    dp->Character = c;
    return LinkedList_append(lp->list, dp);
}

void MyList_delete(MyList *lp, MyData *dp) {
    free(LinkedList_delete(lp->list, dp));
}

void MyList_print(MyList *lp) {
    printf("{\n");
    LinkedList_foreach(MyData *dp, lp->list) {
        printf("    { %d, %d, '%c' }\n", dp->rowPos, dp->colPos, dp->Character);
    }
    printf("};\n");
}

void MyList_filter_diagonal(MyList *lp) {
    LinkedList_foreach(MyData *dp, lp->list) {
        if (dp->rowPos == dp->colPos)
            MyList_delete(lp, dp);
    }
}

int main() {
    MyList *mylist = MyList_alloc();

    MyList_add(mylist, 0, 0, 'A');
    MyData *d1 = MyList_add(mylist, 1, 2, 'B');
    MyList_add(mylist, 2, 2, 'C');
    MyList_add(mylist, 3, 5, 'D');
    MyList_print(mylist);

    MyList_delete(mylist, d1);
    MyList_print(mylist);

    MyList_filter_diagonal(mylist);
    MyList_print(mylist);

    MyList_free(mylist);
    return 0;
}
```